# Reactive Forms: replacing the enter key submit with a different function on some controls

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm learning reactive forms and writing a simple application to help my understanding. I've got a couple text inputs that are used to modify the FormGroup and there is a button in place to execute the function that does so, but I find that I've been naturally hitting enter when trying to fill in those fields and accidentally triggering the form submit. I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent the normal submit behavior on the enter key, but only while some fields have focus, I would like to keep the enter key submit functionality in all other cases and not disable it entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding validations in Reactive form fields.

Plus for specific fields, you can listen for change event / focus event and set a bool to stop form submission. Set disabled property on submit input / submit button with value of bool. So when specific fields will have focus / change event (whatever functionality is required) the submit input / button will be disabled. However, to enable the submit input set bool to false in blur (lost focus) event ((blur)="methodhere($event)") of the field(s). This will again enable the submit input.

Another way is for specific fields, you can listen for change event / focus event and set a bool to stop form process in form submit method. i.e. form will be submitted but will not process further in form submit method.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding validations, and only submit when the forms are valid.

Comment: The thing is that the form can be in a valid state as you're filling out the fields, but valid doesn't mean that the form is finished being filled. Not all fields are required, but I may still want to fill them in when accidentally hitting enter